# Excepciones en Oracle

Tags: oracle, excepciones

Buenos dias estoy creando un store procedure en un paquete del esquema HR ( Oracle )
tengo este codigo  avanzado

```
procedure USP_UPDATE_DEP (p_deptno in number)is

begin
 update departments set department_id = p_deptno where department_id = p_deptno;



end USP_UPDATE_DEP;
```

Mi pregunta es , si quiero actualizar y no exite que excepcion usuaria .

Muchas Gracias, quedo atento a sus respuestas

Comment: Pues uno puede decirle WHEN OTHERS y seguro seguro la atrapa. ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Si no hay datos, no hay excepcion.. solo no va a hacer nada.. no?